# Can someone help me apply the js 'this' keyword to an iterated jq select expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my latest version of this code. The 1st line iterates through the rows of a table skipping over the 1st row. For each row I test to see if the (class='dim') state of one of 8 tag elements (index j) on that row matches the corresponding !'dim' state of a set of 8 filters that the user can toggle. The idea is to set any rows where the 'active' filter / 'dim' tag states line up, to the 'hide' class, so they can disappear from the table that the user sees. The CSS for disappearing it is: .hide {display:none;}

It's that last 'if' statement that's killing me. I've tried dozens of versions but I always get some form of syntax error, undefined variable, etc. In that line of code here I've removed my latest set of +, ', " characters to better show clearly what I'm trying to do.

I don't just want something that works to replace this code. And I'm not interested in the shortest trickiest way to do it. I'd like to see some simple obvious code that I could easily understand a year from now so I can solve problems like this myself. Thanks in advance.

```
var thisRow = $('tbody tr:gt(0)').each(function()    { 
    for (var i=0,j=4;i<8;i++,j++) { 
        if (!$('.butt').eq(i).hasClass('dim')) {                
            if (thisRow.nth-child(j)).hasClass('dim')) $(this).addClass('hide');
            else $(this).removeClass('hide');
        }
    }                                                       
}
```

Above this line is the question as I first asked it. Below this is the complete function in case anyone else might find this useful. Thanks to Mr. Pavlikov for the lesson!

```
function filterTbl()    { //Hide rows that don't satisfy all active filters
  var butts=$('.butt'); //Each filter button has class 'butt'
  $('tbody tr:gt(0)').each(function() { //iterate each table row except the 1st
var thisRow = $(this); //the row being examined
var chilluns = thisRow.children(); //all td's in the row being examined
for (var i=0,j=4;i<8;i++,j++) { 
  if (!butts.eq(i).hasClass('dim')) { //If this filter is active
    //and If the corresponding tag is not active (is 'dimmed'), then hide this row
    if (chilluns.eq(j).hasClass('dim')) thisRow.addClass('hide'); 
    else thisRow.removeClass('hide');   //else unhide this row                                              
  }
}
  }); 
}
```

Comment: well you try to access a variable `thisRow` which is not yet defined. You need to find another way to access this element.

Comment: `thisRow.nth-child(j)` looks problematic.

Comment: @Mathletics Yes, that's the one. I also tried $(this).nth-child(j) unsuccessfully. What I posted is just to show what I'm tying to do but can't.

Comment: @paulo The 1st line defines the var. The row iteration works fine. it's that 2nd 'if' expression that's causing the problem it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should be getting thisRow variable like this (not like you are currently doing)

```
$('tbody tr:gt(0)').each(function() { 
    var thisRow = $(this);                                       
}
```

And what does nth-child stand for? Use [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) correctly or use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) at least if you are willing to compare one row with other rows. I didn't quite understand what are you trying to do, but hope this helps.

And some usefull tips. You do not need to find $('.butt') EVERY TIME in the loop, just find it once before your each loop:

```
var butts = $('.butt');
```

So now you will be able to replace

```
$('.butt').eq(i)
```

with

```
butts.eq(i)
```

This is significant speedup.

Also if n-th child you are trying to find is something that is inside thisRow, find [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and do .eq() on them.

Comment: @Pavlokov Thanks for your suggestions. I just tried: if (thisRow).children:eq(j).hasClass('dim')) - I get unexpected token '.'. I also tried if (thisRow.children:eq(j)).hasClass('dim')) - I get  unexpected token ':'.

Comment: @Pavlokon About the var butts, Since there are possibly hundreds if rows in the table and only 8 filters (butts), wouldn't it be faster to only iterate the rows once testing the row's tags for each active filter?

Comment: @Pavlikov I also incorporated your thisRow=$(this) suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I think I misunderstood your suggestion about the var 'butts'. I'm now trying to put that in. OK it's in and the debugger didn't reject it. Cool! Now it's just the expression: if (thisRow.children:eq(j)).hasClass('dim')) that won't work.

Comment: I just corrected the expression to: if (thisRow.children().eq(j).hasClass('dim')) and it works. Thanks very much for your patience.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw same story with children. Inside each loop you should find them first and put into variable

var children = thisRow.children();

and then use

children.eq(i)